# Why Xcode returns the error "file not found" when i import a header file into my unit test class?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

I am trying to create an unit test for my Objective-C project, and I go through the following steps:

1. File > New > Target
2. Select iOS Unit Testing Bundle
3. I select my project as 'Target to be tested'
4. Xcode creates the .m file for the test

When i import the class i want to test it highlights the line in red and show ViewController.h file not found

What am I missing, why my test class is not able to import my other classes?

I am using Xcode 10.1 and i have never had this problem before

Thanks,

FP

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 10.1 when you import any file in test class, it will show an error "File not found". Just add the `#import` and build the test target anyway; the error warning will resolve itself.

In case of , add the pods separately for both target and test targets.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create new schema for your test target. After that your project resources will be linked to your test target.